# sqlite cursor fetchone() returns 'NoneType'?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

I want to build a function that returns the lowest row count from all tables if the two scores `scor1` and `scor2` are not both 0  :

```
def mini(tablelist):
mini = 1000
for table in tablelist:
    c.execute("SELECT numar_par FROM " + table + "")
    c_min = len(c.fetchall())

    if c_min is None:
        mini = 0
    else:
        c.execute("SELECT scor1 FROM " + table + " ORDER BY numar_par DESC LIMIT 1")
        print("this is fetchone:",c.fetchone(),'from table: ',table)
        scor1 = c.fetchone()[0]
        c.execute("SELECT scor2 FROM " + table + " ORDER BY numar_par DESC LIMIT 1")
        scor2 = c.fetchone()[0]
        sum = int(scor1) + int(scor2)
        if c_min < mini and sum >0:
            mini = c_min
return mini
```

This is the result of the print statement:

```
this is fetchone: ('0',) from table:  a
```

and this is the error:

```
File "D:\pariuri\python\Pycharm test1\Test11 peste 0.5\functii.py", line 181, in mini
scor1 = c.fetchone()[0]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: You have only one entry in the table?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ in table `a` at this moment yes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After executing a query with `execute`, the query results will be available in a query result set, which you can then iterate over with the `c.fetch*` methods.

The thing to note here, is that `fetch*` will *iterate* over the result set, *exhausting* it. This works similar to a generator, which you can only iterate over once.

It works something like this. Imagine a pointer pointing to the next row in the result set to be queried. Running `c.execute` gives a result set looking like this -

```
 head
   |____ Result 1
         Result 2
         .
         .
         Result N
```

After calling `c.fetchone`, `head` will return the next row, and advance by one row -

```
 head    Result 1 (returned)
   |____ Result 2
         .
         .
         Result N
```

Since you have only one row in your table, another call to `fetchone` returns an empty list.

Comment: so every time i run a c.fetchone statement on my select query it will advance one row? why does the print statement print the correct return?

Comment: @MihaiMoldovan Cuz that's the first time you called `fetchone`. So it fetched the singleton row, printed it out. And then, when you called it again in the next line, it returned None.

Comment: So the first c.fetchone is the one from inside the print statement, thank you i learned something. The funny thing is that i put the print statement there to try to debug the error, so i just create another conflict by printing the c.fetchone. any way i tracked the error to the `c_min = len(c.fetchall())

    if c_min is None:` so i guess that `len(fetchall()) will be 0 if fetchall is None, therefore the if statement will never pass. Anyway you answer the problem that appeared from the code i posted and help and me get the real problem

Comment: @MihaiMoldovan No problem. But as a side note, I think a `TypeError:` would be raised if you call `len(None)` :-)

Comment: yeah so the c.fetchall on an empty table returns an empty list, not None, that is why no error, i just checked for the wrong thing with my if statement

Comment: @MihaiMoldovan Okay, great. Will fix my answer then.